# Extract data from JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, object, iteration

How can I assign the "Exchange Rate" value of "18.52005000" in the object below to a JavaScript variable?

```
{
    "Realtime Currency Exchange Rate": {
        "1. From_Currency_Code": "USD",
        "2. From_Currency_Name": "United States Dollar",
        "3. To_Currency Code": "MXN",
        "4. To_Currency_Name": "Mexican Peso",
        "5. Exchange Rate": "18.52005000",
        "6. Last Refreshed": "2018-02-17 12:53:11",
        "7. Time Zone": "UTC"
    }
}
```

I know a little bit of JavaScript - a script I made interfaces with an API for currency conversion rates and I simply need the rate portion to do the rest of my calculations.

I am doing something like this to create the object:

```
var http_response = httpGet(query_url);
var http_response_json = JSON.parse(http_response);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if your Json structure is in the variable "`test`", then do `test["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"]["5. Exchange Rate"]` to access its value of `"18.52005000"`

Answer (score 0):

Like this my good sir:

```
var rate = http_response_json['Realtime Currency Exchange Rate']['5. Exchange Rate']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access object properties in two ways:

1. `object.prop`
2. `object['prop']`

In case of problematic or variable property names, you need to choose 2.

```js
var data = {
    "Realtime Currency Exchange Rate": {
        "1. From_Currency_Code": "USD",
        "2. From_Currency_Name": "United States Dollar",
        "3. To_Currency Code": "MXN",
        "4. To_Currency_Name": "Mexican Peso",
        "5. Exchange Rate": "18.52005000",
        "6. Last Refreshed": "2018-02-17 12:53:11",
        "7. Time Zone": "UTC"
    }
}

var rate = data["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"]["5. Exchange Rate"]

console.log(rate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the JSON object in `http_response_json` then you can do something like this to get the value of the `Exchange Rate`

```js
var http_response_json = {
    "Realtime Currency Exchange Rate": {
        "1. From_Currency_Code": "USD",
        "2. From_Currency_Name": "United States Dollar",
        "3. To_Currency Code": "MXN",
        "4. To_Currency_Name": "Mexican Peso",
        "5. Exchange Rate": "18.52005000",
        "6. Last Refreshed": "2018-02-17 12:53:11",
        "7. Time Zone": "UTC"
    }
};
var value = http_response_json["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"]["5. Exchange Rate"];
console.log(value);
```

Comment: Awesome, worked perfectly and super fast response too!  I love this place.  Upvoted +

Comment: Glad to help you. You can also mark it green and upvote. Remember for more help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var exchangeRate =  http_response_json["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"]["5. Exchange Rate"];
```